# Scraping all urls in a website using scrapy not retreiving complete urls associated with that domain

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to scrape all the urls in websites like https://www.laphil.com/ https://madisonsymphony.org/ https://www.californiasymphony.org/ etc to name the few. I am getting many urls scraped but not getting complete urls related to that domain. I am not sure why it is not scraping all the urls.

**code**

**items.py**

```
import scrapy

class ScraperItem(scrapy.Item):
    # The source URL
    url_from = scrapy.Field()
    # The destination URL
    url_to = scrapy.Field()
```

**my_crawler.py**

```
import re
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from w3lib.url import url_query_cleaner

def process_links(links):
    for link in links:
        link.url = url_query_cleaner(link.url)
        yield link

class myCrawler(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'symphony'
    allowed_domains = ['laphil.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.laphil.com/']
    rules = (
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(
                deny=[
                ],
            ),
            process_links=process_links,
            callback='parse_item',
            follow=True
        ),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        yield {
            'url': response.url
        }
        next_page = response.css('a::attr(href)').extract()
        yield {"sub_url":[response.urljoin(ind_url) for ind_url in next_page]}}
```

**Execution**

```
scrapy crawl symphony --logfile laph.log -o laph.jl -t jsonlines
```

If we go to a url obtained from the crawled url list for example, https://www.laphil.com/events/series/210, there are several links directing from this page like https://www.laphil.com/events/performances/1356/2022-01-08/prokofiev-and-mtt , https://www.laphil.com/events/performances/1337/2021-11-06/reich-adams-and-rachmaninoff etc which are not obtained. How it is possible to scrawl all those urls and avoid duplicate urls in the resultant list

Comment: I'm getting all the urls from the page. Where do you want to remove duplicates? Is it in `yield {"sub_url":next_page}` line?

Comment: @SuperUser Thanks for your kind reply. I am looking to obtain a csv format which can be converted to pandas dataframe for processing which contains a single column having no urls repeating in the column. I tried to save in CLI, but there are problems with reading using pandas module. Also there were lot of duplicate urls present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

spider.py:

```py
import re
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from w3lib.url import url_query_cleaner


def process_links(links):
    for link in links:
        link.url = url_query_cleaner(link.url)
        yield link


class myCrawler(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'symphony'
    allowed_domains = ['laphil.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.laphil.com']
    base_url = 'https://www.laphil.com'

    custom_settings = {
        # in order to reduce the risk of getting blocked
        'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES': {'tempbuffer.middlewares.RotateUserAgentMiddleware': 400, },
        'COOKIES_ENABLED': False,
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 6,
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 2,

        # This settings are a must:
        
        # Duplicates pipeline
        'ITEM_PIPELINES': {'tempbuffer.pipelines.DuplicatesPipeline': 300},

        # In order to create a CSV file:
        'FEEDS': {'csv_file.csv': {'format': 'csv'}}
    }

    rules = (
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(allow_domains='laphil.com'),
            process_links=process_links,
            callback='parse_item',
            follow=True
        ),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        yield {
            'url': response.url
        }

        # see if you really need this loop (since you're parsing all the urls in the domain anyway, and you'll need
        # to filter all those duplicates):

        all_urls = response.css('a::attr(href)').getall()

        # In order to change from relative to absolute url in the pipeline:
        self.base_url = response.url

        for url in all_urls:
            yield {
                'url': url
            }
```

pipeline.py:

```py
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem


class DuplicatesPipeline:
    def __init__(self):
        self.scraped_urls = set()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        url = item['url'].strip()

        # if it's a relative url then convert to absolute url
        if 'http' not in url:
            url = spider.base_url + url
            item['url'] = url

        if url in self.scraped_urls:
            raise DropItem(f'Duplicate url: \"{url}\"')
        else:
            self.scraped_urls.add(url)
            return item
```

1. I didn't add the `middlewares.py` file since it's not a necessary, and it has a lot of lines.
2. In your code instead of `tempbuffer` it should be `your project's name` (you'll need to replace it in the custom_settings for the pipeline).
3. I added to the rules the domain as the only allowed domain so you won't scrape anything you don't want.
4. I verified that the duplicates pipeline works, and that it actually creates a csv file with one column.

Comment: Hello, I'm new to python so I'm not sure how to glue everything together to make it work.  I'm getting error with tempbuffer line. You said to repalce with project name. Not sure how to do that. Can you please update the code so that we can run it?

Comment: Your project's name is selected by you when you [create a new project](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#creating-a-project). If you forget your project's name you can either open `scrapy.cfg` or `settings.py` and find it there. Read the [documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/index.html).

Comment: It gives error NameError: Module 'scrapy_project.middlewares' doesn't define any object named 'RotateUserAgentMiddleware'

Comment: Another issue in your code you have called tempbuffer.pipelines... but you have named file as pipeline.py, shouldn't it be piplelines.py ?

Comment: @Raymond I didn't include the middleware since it's pretty lengthy and not necessary to answer the question, it's just to avoid getting blocked, You can comment this line. Regrading the `pipeline.py` it's just a typo.

Comment: ok so after commenting it does the job but we have got another issue. It takes a lot of time to crawl 17 pages in a website. Next issues, it includes external links and some of the links are not clean. It duplicates trailing slashes after urls.

Comment: It's slow because I limit the requests and increase the download delay in order to [avoid blocking](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#avoiding-getting-banned). You should really read the documentation so you understand the basics of scrapy.